# gRPC stream become canceled

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I'm trying to create a streaming API via gRPC, but my StreamObserver became canceled for some strange reason.
Here is my `.proto` declarations:

```
service Service {
    rpc connect (ConnectionRequest) returns (stream StreamResponse) {}

    rpc act (stream ActRequest) returns (ActResponse) {}
}
```

The idea is that the users will `connect` so the `StreamResponse` will be saved for each user, and then on each `act` the `StreamResponse` will receive the update. Here is the java implementation of the `Service`

```
class ServiceImpl extends ServiceGrpc.ServiceImplBase {
    ............
    @Override
    public void connect(ConnectionRequest request, StreamObserver<StreamResponse> responseObserver) {
        observers.add(responseObserver);
    }

    @Override
    public StreamObserver<ActRequest> act(StreamObserver<ActResponse> responseObserver) {
        return return new StreamObserver<ActRequest>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(ActRequest actRequest) {
                StreamResponse streamResponse = StreamResponse.newBuilder().build();
                observers.forEach(o -> o.onNext(streamResponse));
                actRequest..onCompleted();
            }
            ...............
        };
    }
    ..................
}
```

And here is the client `connect` method:

```
ServiceGrpc.ServiceStub stub = ServiceGrpc.newStub(channel);
new StreamObserver<PlayerResponse>() {
    ........
    @Override
    public void onNext(StreamResponse streamResponse) {
          logger.info("Act: " streamResponse.getData());
    }
    ........
}
ConnectionRequest request = ConnectionRequest.newBuilder().build();
stub.connect(request, streamObserver);
```

And the client `act` method:

```
StreamObserver<ActResponse> observer = new StreamObserver<ActResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(ActResponse actResponse) {
        logger.info("Status: " + actResponse.getSuccess());
    }
    .........
};
StreamObserver<ActRequest> act = stub.act(observer);
act.onNext(MoveRequest.newBuilder().build());
act.onCompleted();
```

When I start both client and server, the client is able to call `connect`. But the method `act` can be called only for the first time. When the client calls `act` for the second time I receive the following exception:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: call already cancelled
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:517)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ServerCallStreamObserverImpl.onNext(ServerCalls.java:335)
```

And in the debug mode I can see that the `StreamObserver<StreamResponse> responseObserver` is `canceled=true`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to call `actRequest..onCompleted();` in the `onNext()` method of the server? Looks like something is wrong there.

Comment: @Ran I guess so. The `actRequest` isn't a stream of actions, it's just one event

Comment: You are calling `.onCompleted()` not sure for which object. and then when the next client call comes you are invoking `o.onNext(streamResponse)`.  Feels like that is the problem.

Comment: @Ran I'm not calling `onCompleted` for `StreamResponse`, only for `ActRequest` and for `ActResponse`. But canceled become `StreamObserver<StreamResponse>`. I have even try not to call `onCompleted` for both of those objects, but the result is the same

Comment: `act.onCompleted();` in the client code. Maybe that is closing the connection.

Comment: @Ran I've tried to omit that, but that doesn't change the behavior, so that's not the case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out why I have got this error. In the client, I'm using `Vaadin` for building the UI. So on the `StreamObserver<ActResponse>#onNext` I'm calling a Vaadin method which throws an exception.

The mistake I made while developing is that I left the `onError` empty as it was a PoC. But this mistake cost me a few hours of debugging.
This is the stupid mistake, but I will let it be here, maybe it could save some time for somebody.